# Django get objects not referenced by foreign key

Tags: django

I have two models like this:

```
class AA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    state = models.IngerField()


class BB(models.Model):
    aa_id = models.ForeignKey(AA)
```

My question is:
How i get all objects AA with state 10 and that are not in BB?

In sql i do something like this:

```
select * from AA 
where  AA.state = 10 and AA.id not in (select aa_id from BB)
```

or

```
select * from AA
left join BB on BB.aa_id = AA.id
where AA.state = 10 and BB.id is null
```

I know that i can get all AA objects and check one by one if BB has foreign key to it. But is not the right thing to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Something like this:

```
AA.objects.filter(state=10, bb=None)
```

Comment: bb is not a field of AA model

Comment: Yes it is, it's the automatically-generated reverse relationship field. Try it, it does work.

Comment: interesting :) I saw `bb_set` and did not realize `bb` is also there, while `bb_set` canot be accessed as a field.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but the answers and comments was really helpful until 9 years after.
Though, even after read the [@Daniel Roseman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman)  great answer (thanks man, your answer helped me a lot), so I checked it out a little bit further at the documentation how it works.

You can read below as it is in the documentation:

> ## [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)
>
> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups, taking care of the
>   SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a
>   relationship, use the field name of related fields across models,
>   separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.
>
> This example retrieves all Entry objects with a Blog whose name is
>   'Beatles Blog':
>
> ```py
> >>> Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='Beatles Blog')
> ```
>
> **It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, use the lowercase name of the model.**

Using django polls tutorial as example, with Questions and Choices as follows:

```py
# models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```py
# Select Questions without related Choices
>>> Question.objects.filter(choice=None)

# Select only Questions with related Choices
>>> Question.objects.exclude(choice=None)

# Select Questions related to Choice with id 1
>>> Question.objects.filter(choice__id=1)
```